# El método addPassenger añade un pasajero al vuelo

Tags: java

El método `addPassenger` añade un pasajero al vuelo.

- Si el pasajero ya existe, entonces debe lanzar una IllegalStateException con el mensaje indicado en ERROR_PASSENGER_ALREADY_IN_FLIGHT.
- Si este método recibe como parámetro el valor null, entonces debe lanzar una NullPointerException con el mensaje ERROR_NULL.
- Si el pasajero pasado como parámetro no tiene pasaporte, entonces debe lanzar una NullPointerException con el mensaje ERROR_NO_PASSPORT.
  ○ El pasajero se guardará en la primera posición libre que haya en el array passengers. Una posición está libre si su valor es null.
- Si el pasajero se ha añadido al vuelo correctamente, este método devolverá true. De lo contrario (p.ej. el vuelo está lleno), devolverá false.

---

```
CONSOLA
Expected :false
Actual   :true
```

Tengo que aumentar el numero de pasajero al añadir un pasajero nuevo pasajero

```
    public boolean addPassenger(Passenger newPassenger) {
        Passenger[] passengers = this.passengers;
        //Si aquest mètode rep com a paràmetre el valor null.
        if (newPassenger == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException(ERROR_NULL);
        }
        //Si el passatger passat com a paràmetre no té passaport.
        else if (newPassenger.getPassport() == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException(ERROR_NO_PASSPORT);
        }
        //Si el passatger ja existeix
        else if (containsPassenger(newPassenger)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(ERROR_PASSENGER_ALREADY_IN_FLIGHT);
        }
        //Comprovar si hi ha espai disponible
        else if (getNumPassengers() < NUM_MAX_PASSENGERS) {

            //Cerca la primera posició lliure i afegir el passatger
            for (int i = 0; i < NUM_MAX_PASSENGERS; i++) {
                //Una posició està lliure si el seu valor és null.
                if (passengers[i] == null) {
                    passengers[i] = newPassenger;
                    return true; //S'ha afegit el passatger amb èxit
                }
            }
        } else {
            //Llançar una excepció si el vol és ple
            throw new IllegalStateException("Number of passengers exceeds the maximum limit.");
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Que tengo mal, como soluciono?
Gracias!

Comment: Buenas, Arianna, si el valor expected es false, supongo que el programa de validación está insertando más pasajeros de los que caben en el vuelo. En lugar de devolver false, parece que tú estás devolviendo true, lo que quiere decir que lo estás añadiendo aunque se supone que no cabe. ¿Cómo has definido tu método getNumPassengers()? ¿Cómo has creado el array de pasajeros? Por otro lado, si se espera un false, no deberías lanzar un excepción cuando se excede el número.

Comment: Muchas gracias! El error estaba en otra parte del código..